# MySQL: preferred column type for (product) prices?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, what is the preferred column type for storing a product's price (or currencies in general)? Google learned me DECIMAL of FLOAT is often used, but I wonder which one is better.

I'm storing prices ranging from 0.01 to 25.00. Of course higher values could also be possible. (Note: I'm not asking for copy-pasta code, I'm just giving you more information which could help you form a more complete answer).

Thanks

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Decimal is the one I would use

> The basic difference between
>   Decimal/Numeric and Float : Float is
>   Approximate-number data type, which
>   means that not all values in the data
>   type range can be represented exactly.
>   Decimal/Numeric is Fixed-Precision
>   data type, which means that all the
>   values in the data type reane can be
>   represented exactly with precision and
>   scale.
>
> Converting from Decimal or Numeric to
>   float can cause some loss of
>   precision. For the Decimal or Numeric
>   data types, SQL Server considers each
>   specific combination of precision and
>   scale as a different data type.
>   DECIMAL(4,2) and DECIMAL(6,4) are
>   different data types. This means that
>   11.22 and 11.2222 are different types though this is not the case for float.
>   For FLOAT(6) 11.22 and 11.2222 are
>   same data types.

Comment: Thanks jdt199 and Razzie, would accept both of your answers  but chose yours for being the most complete one.

Comment: @Sheff DECIMAL(2,2) should be DECIMAL(4,2).
DECIMAL(2,4) should be DECIMAL(6,4).
See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Comment: PrestaShop uses Decimal(20,2). So decimal it is!.
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.7.3.x/install-dev/data/db_structure.sql

Answer (score 32):

Field type "Decimal" is good.

If you have higher prices then you can use `product_price decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,` i.e. you can store prices up to 6 digits with decimal point before 2 digits.

Maximum value for field `product_price decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,` will store price up to 9999.99.

If all prices are between 0.01 to 25.00 then `product_price decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,` will be good, but if you will have higher prices then you can set any values in `decimal(4,2)`.

Answer (score 16):

I would not use float as that can give rounding errors, as it is a floating point type.

Use decimal:

> "The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types are
>   used to store values for which it is
>   important  to preserve exact
>   precision, for example with monetary
>   data."

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Also, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html