# Laravel format_number eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a REST API using Laravel and this is a simply version of my `Product` Eloquent model:

```
- id
- name
- price (float)
```

These are examples of prices: `37.27` `1926.45` `293`.

As per [Laravel Accessor doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) i created this function to add a new attribute to `Product`:

```
public function getMagicPriceAttribute($magic)
{
    return round($magic * $this->price, 2);
}
```

To give users a better experience i need to format `price` as `37,27` `1.926,45` `293`.

So i created:

```
public function getPriceAttribute($price)
{
    return number_format($price);
}
```

The `price` is now formatted as needed but given `number_format` returns a `string`, `getMagicPriceAttribute` is not working correctly and throws errors.

Is there a better approach to handle this?

Comment: What's wrong that it returns a string? What error are you encountering?

Comment: You could always cast it to the correct type before trying to multiply it: `return round($magic * (float)$this->price, 2);`, or even in your `getPriceAttribute()` function, `return (float) number_format($price);` Note: this will format invalid numbers (`number_format('a')` -> `null`) to `0.0`

Comment: Formatting (for better experience) is a `presentation` thing, therefore, best done in the presentation layer also known as the frontend. Also, avoiding `float` and using `decimal` data type for price/columns that involve storing monetary values is common advice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796334/mysql-preferred-column-type-for-product-prices